If match read line by line till blank line and append message using shell script
Need to append message "Line found" in (blank line3) only after match data3 and data4
following is file format.
#
data1 data2
line1
line2
(blank line1)
(blank line2)
#
data3 data4
line3...
line4...
line5...
(blank line3)
(blank line4)
#
line10
line11
line100
(blank line5)
#
line200
line300
(blank line6)


Nothing here is about Linux-specific APIs, removed that tag. Please also read the description of the two remaining tags, one is surely wrong the other is surely useless. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Try this shell script:
#!/bin/bash

input_file="your_file.txt"
temp_file="temp_file.txt"
found_pattern=false

while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ "$line" == "data3 data4" ]]; then
        found_pattern=true
    fi

    if $found_pattern && [[ -z "$line" ]]; then
        echo "Line found" >> "$temp_file"
        found_pattern=false  # Reset the pattern search
    fi
    
    echo "$line" >> "$temp_file"

done < "$input_file"

mv "$temp_file" "$input_file"

echo "Modification done."


Thank you very very much. I was looking same answer.

Your script uses bash specific code, but the OP requested POSIX shell. I suggest that you replace the [[....]] by its [....] equivalents.
